# Obtaining reversed Integer in Java

Tags: java, binary

There is a method in Java that reverses bits in an Integer reverseBytes(). I wanted to try another implementation and this is what I have:

```
public static int reverse(int num) {

        int num_rev = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print((num >> i) & 1);

            if (((num >> i) & 1)!=0) {

                num_rev = num_rev | (int)Math.pow(2, Integer.SIZE-i);
            }

        }
        return num_rev;
}
```

The result num_rev is not correct. Does anyone have any idea how to "reconstruct" the value? Maybe there is a better way to perform it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you give an example of an incorrect result?  Have you tried to debug this?

Comment: are you trying to reverse the order of _all_ 32 bits, or just swap from one endian form to the other (i.e. swap bytes)

Comment: I'm trying to reverse the order of all 32 bits. An example would be: 110 which should be reversed to 0110000000...(add all 0's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way would to reverse bits would be via bit manipulation, and certainly *not* via floating point math routines!

e.g (nb: untested).

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        y <<= 1;       // make space
        y |= (x & 1);  // copy LSB of X into Y
        x >>>= 1;      // shift X right
    }
    return y;
}
```

Because `x` is right shifted and `y` left shifted the result is that the original LSB of `x` eventually becomes the MSB of `y`.

A nice (and reasonably well known) method is this:

```
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int x)
{
    x = (((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1));
    x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
    x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
    x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
    return ((x >> 16) | (x << 16));
}
```

This is actually C code, but as Java doesn't have `unsigned` types to port to Java all you should need to do is remove the `unsigned` qualifiers and use `>>>` instead of `>>` to ensure that you don't get any "sign extension".

It works by first swapping every other *bit*, then every other *pair* of bits, then every other *nybble*, then every other *byte*, and then finally the top and bottom 16-bit words.  This actually works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I keep getting the same result; I need to test your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You're using an int cast. You should be doing (long)Math.pow(... The problem with int casting is that pow(2, n) will always be a positive number, so pow(2, 31) casted to an int will be rounded to (2^31)-1, because that's the largest positive int. The bit field for 2^31-1 is 0x7ffffff, but in this case you want 0x80000000, which is exactly what the lower 32 bits of the casted long will be.
2. You're doing pow(2, Integer.Size - i). That should be Integer.SIZE - i - 1. You basically want to take bit 0 to the last bit, bit 1 to the second last and so on. However, the last bit is bit 31, not bit 32. Your code right now is trying to set bit 0 to bit Integer.SIZE-0 == 32, so you need to subtract 1.

The above is assuming this is just for fun. If you really need to reverse bits, however, *please* don't use floating point ops. Do what some of the another answers suggest.

Answer (score -1):

why you don't want to use:

```
public static int reverseBytes(int i) {
    return ((i >>> 24)           ) |
           ((i >>   8) &   0xFF00) |
           ((i <<   8) & 0xFF0000) |
           ((i << 24));
}
```

edited:
Integer has also:

```
public static int reverse(int i)
```

> Returns the value obtained by
>   reversing the order of the bits in the
>   two's complement binary representation
>   of the specified int value.

Comment: and have you tried reverse(int) method? Could you give example what you expect and what it returns?

Comment: I wanted to implement it on my own rather than use the method java provides. If we start with the int 110, then I would like to get 0110000....and so on. Thanks for help!